# Full disk encryption with LUKS?

Tags: linux, penetration-test, disk-encryption, luks, grub

I encrypted my Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.3 with LVM/LUKS during the installation process. If I turn off the computer, is the brute force the only attack available for getting the password and accessing the files? I think it doesn’t encrypt the /bios partition - is that a problem? I’ve seen some articles about some Evil Maid attack as well?

Comment: If it is off and stays off then a brute force attack (against the master key or Chris Garcia himself) is the only option. If it is on and you enter(ed) your password then there are more options. In the linked related threads you'll find some relevant discussions.

Answer (score 1):

If the attacker has physical access to your PC they can:

- Implant a HW keyboard logger and you're completely compromised.
- Alter the [initrd](https://github.com/AonCyberLabs/EvilAbigail) (inital ramdisk) - the so called Evil Maid attack and implant any malware.
- They can potentially alter your UEFI firmware and implant undeletable malware which cannot be detected by your OS.

If you're concerned about this, the best protection would be do use Apple hardware, i.e. MacBook or certified Google Chromebooks. They have protections against 2 and 3, but 1 is still possible though extremely complicated.

Comment: "It fully protects against " Proofs? For some 2+3 protection Linux also has some options (Secure Boot, UKI, Heads,...)

Comment: @secfren UKI is **not** implemented in any existing stable released distro yet, Fedora 38 is not yet released. Apple has the strongest all around HW protection of any personal hardware out there. That's a bloody fact. Most x86 motherboards happily allow to flash whatever crap you come up with. That's impossible with Apple where every piece of software if signed and cannot run unless the hardware allows it.

Comment: I can give you a password protected MacBook and you're welcome to subvert its boot process. Meanwhile at Pwn2Own 2023 fully updated Ubuntu was hacked 5 times.  Only a single attack against MacOS was demonstrated. Nothing for iOS.

Comment: Speaking of the boot process for MacBooks. Please peruse https://support.apple.com/en-us/guide/security/secac71d5623/web x86 UEFI PC is a joke in this regard. BTW, Chrome Books are also very well protected. Actually it's worth adding to the answer.

Comment: "That's impossible" - Sure? tbh, I am not aware of any current *public* ways to subvert MacOS early during the boot process. Though there have been some *public* ones in the past. Problem with those "secure" devices is you throw away lots of security via telemetry and with a deeply locked down system in case of an successful attack the protection will be used against the user. Locking down, in the way Apple does, also makes security research harder for researchers on a budget (those with bigger budgets remaining).

Comment: *via telemetry* Apple AFAIK is not known for siphoning your private data. *"and with a deeply locked down system in case of an successful attack the protection will be used against the user*" - that's a price many are willing to pay to get near 100% security. A friend of mine does his banking and trading exclusively on his iPad and he feels safe. He doesn't feel safe with neither Windows, nor Android.

Comment: "Apple AFAIK is not known for siphoning your private data." I disagree, and it is not only Apple who has access to Apples telemetry data. It all depends on your thread model. Android/Apple/Microsoft is US. Unlikely the average thug will get your data. Also unlikely that your data gets used against you when you are from the US. But if you live in China, Russia ... the thug could be the US itself. There is a reason why countries like to keep telemetry inside the country, come up with their own hard/software or try to kick out foreign telemetry (like the US doing with TikTok ;) ).

Comment: If we go by this reasoning you can only trust hardware which is 1) fully open (blueprints, etc) 2) contains no ROM of any kind 3) which is possible to inspect and verify that it matches the blueprints which is just impossible unless you have an electron microscope and a ton of time 4) runs open source software whose entire build chain can be followed and reproduced. IOW it is impossible nowadays. Last time it was possible maybe in the early 90s. And you've got to be an IC engineer and programmer simultaneously.

Comment: And then there's a ton of equipment to get information off you remotely (using sound waves, Wi-Fi signal, mains/electricity, lasers and visible light scanners). And this is actually done against certain people.

Comment: Depending on your thread model you could (and maybe should) do all of that. Ideally start at the easy levels (like telemetry) and move down to analyzing your CPU die. Things get more expensive, but they also get more expensive for an attacker if he is caught. Which makes a requirement  for "we need an electron microscope"-defenses unlikely. Fully open is relatively easy (and not a strict requirement actually), neither is ROM a strict requirement (makes things harder and easier) for 3) i'd say it is unlikely and there are cheaper ways to check, 4) doable. Is Apple good at any of those points?

Comment: Nah, Apple is not good but their track record so far has been stellar.

Comment: https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/023/021/e02e5ffb5f980cd8262cf7f0ae00a4a9_press-x-to-doubt-memes-memesuper-la-noire-doubt-meme_419-238.png

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt the /boot partition with LUKS1 and thus protect initial ramdisk and kernel image from tempering. It requires GRUB2.

I don't think vanilla Ubuntu installation can set this up (I wouldn't trust Ubuntu for managing my security anyway).

But, I have never looked into the security implication of using LUKS1 over LUKS2. And even though, attack surface is limited, GRUB2 might have vulnerabilities too prior to decryption.

Of course that does not protect against hardware tempering or firmware tempering for example.

Some documentation: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dm-crypt/Specialties

My opinion is that disk encryption is only good to encrypt data at disk in case the disk (computer) is stolen.